# Externalize Tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat

I have a DataSource configuration in context.xml. Is it possible not to hard-code database parameters in that file? For example, use an external properties file, and load the parameters from it?

Something, like this:

context.xml:

```
  <Resource
  name="jdbc/myDS" auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
  url="${db.url}"
  username="${db.user}"
  password="${db.pwd}"
  maxActive="2"
  maxIdle="2"
  maxWait="-1"/>
```

db.properties:

```
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:sid
db.user=test
db.pwd=test
```

Comment: The context.xml file is already an external file. Why do you think you need another one?

Answer (score 14):

As stated [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Property_replacements), you could do this in the following way.

1.Download tomcat library to get the interface definition, for instance by defining maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.47</version>
    </dependency>
```

2.Next step is to create a com.mycompany.MyPropertyDecoder in the following way:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils;
public class MyPropertyDecoder implements IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource  {
    @Override
    public String getProperty(String arg0) {
        //TODO read properties here
        return null;
    }
}
```

3.Put MyPropertyDecoder.class into **tomcat7/lib** folder
4.Define org.apache.tomcat.util.digester. PROPERTY_SOURCE property at **tomcat7/conf/catalina.properties** as following:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=com.mycompany.MyPropertyDecoder
```

5.Update your context.xml with properties vars

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB"
           auth="Container"
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           username="root"
           password="${db.password}"
           driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?autoReconnect=true"
           ...
```

6.Put **application.properties** file somewhere in your project/container
7.Make sure **MyPropertyDecoder** correctly reads **application.properties**
8.Enjoy!

PS Also there is a similar approach described for [tc Server](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.0/admin/html/ch04s07.html).

Comment: Great, this works for me. Do you know if the same approach can be used to enable/disable a code snippet, that is by using an entry value of the property file like a flag?

Comment: Objnewbie, using properties files for enabling/disabling some functionality of your app is ok. However you shouldn't implement Tomcat's IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource for this. Because this is just for Tomcat container to understand your properties files. In your scenario I would suggest using properties files and some handy ways to reading it, for instance @Value annotation from Spring framework.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately our team don't use Spring, but Struts 1.3.10. I posted [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589018/java-web-app-tomcat-and-configuration-files-properties)

Comment: Can the application.properties file be put in another location different from Tomcat lib folder? From some tests, it seems to me that it's not possible (for example in WEB-INF project folder)

Comment: Sure it can. Generally, the location should be present in classpath, and that would work.

Comment: if I put it in `WEB-INF/classes` or `WEB-INF/lib`, changing also the web.xml in different ways, I obtain an `Unexpected exception resolving reference java.lang.NumberFormatException` (this not happens if the file is in tomcat lib)

Answer (score 5):

It is easy with [context deploy descriptors](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html), which look like:

```
<Context docBase="${basedir}/src/main/webapp"
         reloadable="true">
    <!-- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html -->
    <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.VirtualDirContext"
               extraResourcePaths="/WEB-INF/classes=${basedir}/target/classes,/WEB-INF/lib=${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
            virtualClasspath="${basedir}/target/classes;${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true"/>

    <Parameter name="min" value="dev"/>
    <Environment name="app.devel.ldap" value="USER" type="java.lang.String" override="true"/>
    <Environment name="app.devel.permitAll" value="true" type="java.lang.String" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

There are several places where you can put this config, for my opinion best option is `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/$APP.xml`

In above XML `Context` can hold custom `Loader` [org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html) (available in modern Tomcat 7, you can add **own separate classpath per application** to your `.properties` files), `Parameter` (accessed via `FilterConfig.getServletContext().getInitParameter(name)`) and `Environment` (accessed via `new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env").lookup("name")`)

See discussion at:

- [Adding a directory to tomcat classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300780/adding-a-directory-to-tomcat-classpath)
- [Can I create a custom classpath on a per application basis in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345793/can-i-create-a-custom-classpath-on-a-per-application-basis-in-tomcat)
- [How to read a properties file outside my webapp context in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318578/how-to-read-a-properties-file-outside-my-webapp-context-in-tomcat)
- [Configure Tomcat to use properties file to load DB connection information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380793/configure-tomcat-to-use-properties-file-to-load-db-connection-information)
- [Should you set up database connection properties in server.xml or context.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064260/tomcat-jndi-configuration-best-practice)

**UPDATE** [Tomcat 8 change syntax for](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) `<Resources>` and `<Loader>` elements, corresponding part now look like:

```
<Resources>
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                   webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" base="${basedir}/target/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
                   webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" base="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib" />
</Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is possible. You have to register [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to your `web.xml` like this:

```
<!-- at the beginning of web.xml -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mycompany.servlets.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Source of `com.mycompany.servlets.ApplicationListener`:

```
package com.mycompany.servlets;

public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // this method is invoked once when web-application is deployed (started)

        // reading properties file
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("path/to/db.properties")    
            properties.load(fis);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        // creating data source instance
        SomeDataSourceImpl dataSource = new SomeDataSourceImpl();
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(properties.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(properties.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty("db.pwd"));

        // storing reference to dataSource in ServletContext attributes map
        // there is only one instance of ServletContext per web-application, which can be accessed from almost anywhere in web application(servlets, filters, listeners etc)
        final ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        servletContext.setAttribute("some-data-source-alias", dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // this method is invoked once when web-application is undeployed (stopped) - here one can (should) implement resource cleanup etc
    }

}
```

And then, somewhere in web-application code to access `dataSource`:

```
ServletContext servletContext = ...; // as mentioned above, it should be accessible from almost anywhere
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) servletContext.getAttribute("some-data-source-alias");
// use dataSource
```

`SomeDataSourceImpl` is some concrete implementation of [javax.sql.DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html). Please advise if you doesn't use specific `DataSource`s (like [ComboPooledDataSource](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html) for connection pooling) and don't know how to obtain it - I will post how to bypass this.

`some-data-source-alias` - is just `String` alias(key) for your `DataSource` instance in `ServletContext` attribute map. Good practice is to give aliases prepended with package name like `com.mycompany.mywebapp.dataSource`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I am sure it works perfectly. I wonder if exists some out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Do you mean solution which uses `JNDI` with Tomcat's `DataSource`?

Comment: Basically yes. I wonder if Tomcat accepts some kind of variables in context.xml, so Administrator can hold these variables in an external properties-file.

Comment: As per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html: one can specify `JNDI` resources in `jndi.properties` file, but it should reside either in application classpath or in `JAVA_HOME/lib/jndi.properties` which is quite limited.

And it looks like Tomcat uses only `JNDI` functionality in `context.xml`, so most probably it's not possible to have something like `url="${db.url}"` there referencing value from some external file. I've seen situation where `context.xml` is preprocessed by Ant before packing into `.war` file.

Comment: Thanks You. So it seems that there is no out-of-the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Tomcat 7, you can write your own `org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource` implementation read variables written like "${...}" in `context.xml`. You'll need to set the system property `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE` to point to your `PropertySource` implementation.