# How to read a properties file outside my webapp context in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, servlets, properties

I have this requirement that my webapp needs to read from a properties file outside the Tomcat webapps directory, for example from $CATALINA_HOME/properties/myapp.properties. I have tried several things but so far no luck

Comment: A file is a file; give it a path and read it.

Comment: Yeah this is easy to do. It's not senseless, there are reasons for it.

Comment: I think the file will be shared by multiple projects, I post an answer, hope it can give you the hint.

Comment: This is required for configuration, when we deploy the same war to different boxes (dev, qa, etc). We use $TOMCAT/conf/xxx.properties files, and have a jar (with classes to read the named property files and the properties themselves) that different applications use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are multiple approaches .

1. Use an Environmental variable
2. Use a System Property
3. Set it as a Application Context Param in Web.xml

Heres a sample ,that shows`Option 1 and Option 2`

```
try {

    //Use Any Environmental Variable , here i have used CATALINA_HOME
    String propertyHome = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");           
    if(null == propertyHome){

        //This is a system property that is  passed
        // using the -D option in the Tomcat startup script
        propertyHome  =  System.getProperty("PROPERTY_HOME");
    }


    String filePath= propertyHome+"/properties/myapp.properties";

    Properties property = new Properties();         
    property.load(SystemTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your second approach with System Property "catalina.home" This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the option to configure via Tomcat context descriptors.

These XML-documents are placed into the folder `tomcat/conf/Catalina/<host>/*.xml`

This refers to:  [Externalizing Tomcat webapp config from .war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956651/externalizing-tomcat-webapp-config-from-war-file)

Answer (score 1):

In our project that we config the path of file as vm arguments which will stored in the tomcat properties and in the code, use `System.getProperty(the parameter you config)` to get the path and read the properties file, then get the results.

Comment: Yeah, but in case Tomcat and if I need read file somewhere in class .... implements ServletContextListener {} I got WAR related path ! Is it possible something using for example SPRING to get path outside of WAR ? file:d:/my/path/toFile.log

Answer (score 0):

We have put the path of webapp-config directory as follows:

**/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/system-properties-location.properties**

where
**webapp**= name of your webapp file

Here are the contents of system-properties-location.properties file:

**location=/var/lib/tomcat7/webapp-configs/webapp**

It points to an external location to pull environment specific properties from. This way we can deploy same war in dev , staging and prod without modifying war contents.