# Java web app: Tomcat and configuration files .properties

Tags: java, tomcat7, config, struts-1, properties-file

I have a java web app with Tomcat as servlet container.

I would to use different configuration files for different build configurations, i.e.

> 1) demo.properties
>
> 2) real.properties
>
> 3) test.properties

in which I would to specify the database name, db user and password (now for the db I use JNDI resource configuration in app `context.xml`), if send mail should be enabled or not (now I have two methods whose content I have to comment or not according to the purpose), some css image paths and some other stuff.

If it's possible to do so, how can I extrapolate db connection from `context.xml`? and How can I prevent to send email if my app is test or demo?

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to Anton Shchastnyi's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468881/externalize-tomcat-configuration), I succeeded in extrapolating db connection parameters from `context.xml` (say in `configApp.properties`).

The `configApp.properties` must be in Tomcat lib folder together with .class which implements IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource.

So, how could I generalize this solution such that it can be used for different web app deployment? (I prepare the .war locally, then it's deployed on remote server)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468881/externalize-tomcat-configuration