# Read common external property file in Java Webapp and java normal app

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, properties-file

I know this question has answered many a time with most useful answer as below,

[Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app)

However, We have some special requirement as below,

1. Webapp will be deployed to tomcat.
2. Normal java app in form of .jar will be placed under folder /myapp
3. myappConfig.property file will be placed under /myapp

**Directory Structure on client machine**

```
/myapp
   /myapp.jar
   /assests/myappConfig.property
   /tomcat/webapps/myapp.war
```

Basically **myapp.jar** and **myapp.war** will access sql db connection values for MySql database connection and db operations.

Accessing myappConfig.property from myapp.jar --> Working fine

```
        File jarPath = new File(Myapp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        String propertiesPath = jarPath.getParent();
        System.out.println(" propertiesPath-" + propertiesPath);
        mainProperties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesPath + "\\assets\\myapp.property"));
```

Can anyone help/suggest how to implement,

Accessing myappConfig.property file from mywebapp,

**provided run time change in myappConfig.property file does not required myapp.war to be redeployed**

Thanks for your help in advance.

**edit**

Below is the steps in which we want to deliver the project to client.

1. Below is my app directory

   ```
   /myapp
     /myapp.jar
     /assests/myappConfig.property
     /tomcat/webapps/myapp.war
   ```
2. pack everything in one package with some packaging tool.
3. Run this package in client machine at any location and it will have same directory structure as above
4. Here, I do not want to hard code any location in webapp or tomcat for "/assests/myappConfig.property"
5. Normal Java app I can read property file but for wepapp I am not getting clear idea for how to do that?

Comment: better to use property-file's value persist into Database if you want to change at runtime without re-deployment then.

Comment: @vishalgajera as I mentioned the property file contains the db connection vlaues, so unless I read property values webapp cannot access db.

Comment: your req. looks like unclear, one way you mentioned that you want to change prop. file at run-time without re-deployment and one way you said database-credentials are then. how it's possible.

Comment: @vishalgajera ok, just a small query can't we chnage db string while webapp is running?

Comment: you can change it, but you had change property file!! means now get update of that prop. file you has to re-deploy it for get changes into web-app. that's why i am recommending if you don't likewise then store it into databse.

Comment: @vishalgajera understood, but is that correct way if we read updated property values by a method and then we do not need redeploy

Comment: Why would he need to redeploy? It's just a resource like a picture or anything else. If he's using JDBC, he just connects elsewhere.

Comment: @SchoolBoy sorry. can't you get updated value(properties file's value) without re-deoploy. let me know if it's so then.

Comment: @vishalgajera So you are telling me that if I change my profile picture on your website you have to re-deploy your webapp to display it? If you say no, why is a picture different from a text file? You can read it anytime. He's not talking about JPA config.

Comment: @Peter it's different scenario what i discuss. but if counting that profile picture as a part of web-app then sure you need to re-deploy too.

Comment: It's an outside resource, he will be able to read it without any problems.

Comment: @Peter parden me, it's out of my focus. appreciate!!

Comment: It's ok, I'm glad you realized. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `<context>` to tomcat/conf/server.xml (in this example, linux path):

```
<Context docBase="/home/yourusername/tomcat/assests" path="/assets" />
```

If you are using Windows:

```
<Context docBase="C:\path\to\myapp\assets" path="/assets" />
```

And then you can access it like any other resource within your webapp (e.g.: /assets/myappConfig.property).

If you are using JDBC for example, you could store the connection properties in a Singleton and request it from there, and that class could take care of change checks on that file.

Comment: can you share small example for Singleton?

Comment: Like this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm

Comment: I only recommended using it not to confuse old and new configs. Just read the config file every X minute with this class and if it's changed set the correct connection details.

Comment: the <Context > method could you elaborate more and also I think in this case the property file's path need to be hard coded, correct?

Comment: @SchoolBoy yes, you technically give an alias to the "hard coded" property file path. (Actually, setting a path in a property isn't hard coding.)

Comment: Thanks, I did not get exactly what you said. can you give example. also JFYI, I am using windows machine.

Comment: @SchoolBoy I've added the Windows example to the answer. You should be able to access the file then as I described.