# How to avoid writing Java code in Eclipse/NetBeans when using Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, tomcat, netbeans

I am currently helping a small hosting company. There is no experience existing in regards to writing Java code.

They now have the order of a customer to host a complicated product using Tomcat, which needs some prelimanary work to be done beforehands. In detail, some Java Proxy classes need to be created using NetBeans (and Eclipse).

I think this is subject to be done by the software manufacturer. However when starting to work with this topic following a documentation of the manufacturer I see that i.e. when creating a WSDL the connect to an internal server (inclusing user name/password) is necessary.

So I wonder how to have this work to be done by the manufacturer without having access to our webserver? I.e. creating a WAR-file?

Comment: Question & your architecture unclear. What are "Java Proxy classes", what is the customer supplying and what are you supposed to provide? How would a `.war` help?

Comment: Customer is supposed to run a website, including a Web Service API too. The subject is to generate .java-files first (via NetBeans) and .class-files secondly (via Eclipse).

Comment: That's not clarifying much. If there is no established practice in place talk to the customer. They will know if they need something beforehand or if they can make it configurable via some server-provided properties. Code needs to be written in specific ways to be configurable in the first place, e.g. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956651/externalizing-tomcat-webapp-config-from-war-file - But beware, the app gets told passwords and it can leak them to the customer if they want. Don't rely on those passwords being secret

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately things are not that easy. Customer neither have a clue about what needs to be done beforehand. They just know, what should run in the end in the ISP´s environment. Who later on is in charge of creating Java code/classes is completely not of interest for them. They are just stating: "Developer and ISP - clarify between you guys".

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the developers should create a deployable artifact that - if the Tomcat itself is configured correctly - simply needs to be deployed and will run out of the box. That is the war file! So basically there is no need to access the hosting company server itself, neither to write any code in Eclipse/NetBeans to get the application up and running. If the customers say so, they either have a really weird code base there, or they simply do not know what they are talking about.

Comment: Thanks so far. How about web server names the developers do not know? How can those be implemented in an easy manner? Via a specific configuration file? Or are the developers supposed to contact the hosting company beforehands in order to receive such a web server name + user name + password? Especially the latter information should not leave the house per security nature...