# How to include external config.properties in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a file config.properties which I use in order toconfigure the db connection in java but when I run the webapp in tomcat it says that the file doesn't exists because it can't find the file

How can I include this file?

Comment: It needs to be in the classpath. If you want it to be external to your application then you need to explicitly tell your application where to find the config file.

Comment: @DaveRlz and how can I do this?

Comment: You did not say where you placed that file.

Comment: please add the code which makes use of your config.properties. Also, the location where the file(config.properties) is saved. need a screenshot of the location.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, configuration files are put in the WEB-INF/ and from a servlet we get the stream to the file using `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF<folder name>/<file name>")`. It is kept in WEB-INF since no file can be accessed from within WEB-INF with browser. This is more or less a standard practice. There is one other option to configure DB connection through DataSource configured into Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with keeping config in WEB-INF is that it isn't flexible and requires rebuilds for config changes, such as when moving from one machine to another. This is not good practice.

Take a look at this answer for how to place you config file elsewhere:

[Externalizing Tomcat webapp config from .war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956651/externalizing-tomcat-webapp-config-from-war-file)