# Why won't my Spring application run in a container?

Tags: spring, docker, amazon-ecs

My Spring (version 5.1.1) application runs fine on my Windows development environment, and it has run fine on Ubuntu EC2 instances for months.  We are now trying to containerize the application to run on ECS.  The exact same thing that runs on my desktop won't launch correctly when deployed within a Docker container.

My application is annotation-based, with no Spring XML config files.  I am running tomcat 7.0.30 on my desktop and 7.0.96 in the container.

Here is the relevant part of the stacktrace that is printed during Spring startup:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1212)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:337)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:242)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5037)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1018)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2020)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Oct 04, 2019 8:16:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Oct 04, 2019 8:16:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/api-1] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 04, 2019 8:16:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

Here is my WebSecruityConfigAdapter:

```
import com.autoap.api.resources.ResourceConstants;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Log4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * List of resources with an unsecured GET method, but the other HTTP methods are still secured
     */
    private final String[] PUBLIC_GET_RESOURCES = {
            ResourceConstants.LIST_PATH + "/**",
            ResourceConstants.MAKES_PATH + "/**",
            ResourceConstants.MODELS_PATH + "/**",
            ResourceConstants.PING_PATH,
            ResourceConstants.REPORTS_PATH, // Just the root of the Reports path, not wildcarded.
            ResourceConstants.SEARCH_PATH + "/**",
            ResourceConstants.STYLES_PATH + "/**",
            ResourceConstants.VEHICLES_PATH + ResourceConstants.VIN_PATH + "/**",
            ResourceConstants.VEHICLES_PATH + "/*",
            ResourceConstants.XTEMPLATE_PATH + "/**"
    };

    /**
     * List of resources that are wide-open (unsecured GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.
     */
    private final String[] UNSECURED_RESOURCES = {
            ResourceConstants.USERS_PATH + "/**",
            ResourceConstants.FEEDBACK_PATH,
            ResourceConstants.EVENTS_PATH,
            ResourceConstants.API_DOCS + "/**"
    };

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        log.debug("Configuring WebSecurity...");

        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PUBLIC_GET_RESOURCES)
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Configuring HttpSecurity...");

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(UNSECURED_RESOURCES).authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }
}
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>AutoAp API</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.autoap.api.log.LogConfigurationUpdatesWatchListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.autoap.api.spring.SpringConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.autoap.api.jersey.JerseyConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is my SpringConfiguration.java:

```
import com.autoap.api.enums.SystemPropertyType;
import com.autoap.api.service.SystemPropertyService;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

@Log4j
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.autoap"})
@EnableAsync
public class SpringConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    public static Integer DEFAULT_CORE_POOL_SIZE = 128;

    private SystemPropertyService spService;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfiguration(SystemPropertyService spService) {
        log.info("Starting Spring Configuration...");
        this.spService = spService;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        int corePoolSize = DEFAULT_CORE_POOL_SIZE;

        String corePoolSystemProperty = spService.getValue(SystemPropertyType.SPRING, "core-pool-size");

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(corePoolSystemProperty)) {
            corePoolSize = Integer.valueOf(corePoolSystemProperty);
        }

        log.info("Setting Async Core Pool Size to " + corePoolSize);

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The only difference I can think of is the fact that I'm using maven to launch tomcat and my application in my dev environment.  In the container it's just starting up tomcat, which sees my war file and loads it.  But that's how it runs in Production on an Ubuntu EC2 instance, so I'm stumped.  Suggestions?

UPDATE: As requested, here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.autoap</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.18</jersey.version>
        <!-- Jetty that uses asm version compatible with other dependencies in the project: <= 8.1.14.v20131031 -->
        <!-- Jetty that uses Java 6: <= 8... -->
        <jetty.version>8.1.14.v20131031</jetty.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springframework.security.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</springframework.security.version>
        <springframework.ws.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.ws.version>
        <springframework.data.version>1.4.1.RELEASE</springframework.data.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.7</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- cglib is needed by Spring -->
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.438</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
            <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
            <version>[r136,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- database driver dependency for test scope -->
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.170</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- see http://www.jayway.com/2013/04/12/solving-asm-conflicts-after-upgrading-to-groovy-2-1/ -->
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <!-- change groovy-all dependency when this version changes -->
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.codemodel</groupId>
            <artifactId>codemodel</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20131018</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- database driver dependency for production scope -->
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- see http://www.jayway.com/2013/04/12/solving-asm-conflicts-after-upgrading-to-groovy-2-1/ -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <!-- needs to be same version that REST Assured depends on -->
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- prevent the far-out possibility that jersey-spring3 pulls in a different Spring -->
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis-typehandlers-jsr310 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-typehandlers-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>

                <configuration>
                    <!-- The name of your generated source package -->
                    <packageName>com.autoap.api.chrome</packageName>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>http://services.chromedata.com/Description/7a?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-build-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/build/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.build.finalName}</warName>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <!-- don't include an autoap.properties so that configuration can be externalized,
                                                    e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14003409/1325216 -->
                    <!--<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/autoap.properties</packagingExcludes>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post also your `pom.xml` file.  My guess is that the dependencies are not being packaged correctly, thus they're available in the dev environment as part of the devDependency but not in the war file package.

Comment: I added a trimmed version of my pom.xml to the question body.  (had to trim because I hit the character limit)